# The expected number of drawings until the first time a duplication occurs.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The original problem is

> There are $N$ coupons numbered $1$ to $N$ in a bag. Draw one after another with replacement. What is the expected number of drawings until the first time a duplication occurs.

The answer is $\sum_{k=0}^{N}\dfrac{(N)_k}{N^k}$, where $(N)_k=N(N-1)\cdots(N-k+1)$

I calculate it in another way. Let $X$ be number of drawings until the first time a duplication occurs. Then we have $P(X=k+1)=\frac{(N)_k}{N^k}\cdot\frac{k}{N}$, and hence $\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{(N)_k}{N^k}\cdot\frac{k}{N}\cdot (k+1)$.

The calculation shows that they are identical, but I cannot figure out a way to prove that.
I believe there are some connections between these two answers. The first answer does not consider the draw at $k+1$, while these events can be further decomposed to a series of events that the duplication occurs at $k+1,k+2,..., N+1$. However, I cannot figure it out.

Here are my two questions:

1. How the answer $\sum_{k=0}^{N}\dfrac{(N)_k}{N^k}$ is obtained?
2. Is there a connection between the two answers? For example, a bijection between the events in these two solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of calculating $E(X)$ for a non-negative integer valued random variable $X$. First, there's
$$ E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k P(X = k), $$
as you used. The other is
$$ E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X \ge k). $$
See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4277306/132487) for the equivalence.

Calculating $P(X \ge n)$ is straight-forward:
$$ P(X \ge k) = (N)_k / N^k. $$
Basically, just do the same as your idea, but don't require the $(k+1)$-th draw to be a duplicate. Plugging this into the second version of $E(X)$ gives the required answer.

Comment: Oh, I know that equivalence and have tried to use it. But I did not realize that $P(X\ge k)=(N)_k / N^k$ so I calculate it using the sum. Thank you for pointing this out!